# Не получается подключиться к webdav на С

Tags: c, webdav

Используя библиотеку neon написал код:

```
ne_uri uri;

ne_uri_parse("http://192.168.1.160:80", &uri);

ne_inet_addr* inet_addr = ne_iaddr_parse(uri.host, ne_iaddr_ipv4);

ne_sock_init();

ne_socket* socket = ne_sock_create();

if(ne_sock_connect(socket, inet_addr, uri.port)){
    fprintf(stdout, "Socket failed: %s\n", ne_sock_error(socket));

    ne_iaddr_free(inet_addr);
    ne_uri_free(&uri);
    ne_sock_exit();

    exit(1);
}

ne_session* session = ne_session_create(uri.scheme, uri.host, uri.port);

res = ne_mkcol(session, "/index");
...
```

Запустил тестовый сервер по локальной сети по адресу http://192.160.1.160:80
При запуске программы получаю:

```
Start
Socket failed: Too many open files
```

Не могу понять почему не получается подключится.

```
sysctl -a | grep maxfile
kern.maxfiles: 191353
kern.maxfilesperproc: 172215


ulimit -a
cpu time               (seconds, -t)  unlimited
file size           (512-blocks, -f)  unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d)  33554432
stack size              (kbytes, -s)  524288
core file size      (512-blocks, -c)  unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m)  unlimited
locked memory           (kbytes, -l)  64
max user processes              (-u)  10227
open files                      (-n)  172215
virtual mem size        (kbytes, -v)  unlimited
swap limit              (kbytes, -w)  unlimited
socket buffer size       (bytes, -b)  unlimited
pseudo-terminals                (-p)  unlimited
kqueues                         (-k)  unlimited
umtx shared locks               (-o)  unlimited
```

Comment: Попробуйте выложить тут код *минимального законченного примера* (сами же видите, за 5 часов никто не захотел лезть в гит)

Comment: @avp, я слазил :) Увидел что это сообщение выводится при ошибке [в этой строке](https://github.com/alexmlw/y.disk/blob/master/src/webdav.c#L33). Прикинул, что для начала надо бы встать на ней в отладчике и посмотреть аргументы, а перед этим добавить парочку отладочных выводов... Дальше в голове всплыла фраза "работа за автора" и интерес пропал :)

Comment: Попробуйте в начале обнулить `errno` и проверьте результаты вызовов всех  `ne_...`

Comment: Осваиваю по немного gdb. Обратил внимание что функции почему-то зацикливаются. Все от ne_uri_parse и до ne_sock_connect повторяется много раз. Добавил `char ch[256];
    printf("%s\n", ne_iaddr_print(inet_addr, ch, sizeof(ch)));` запустил `./test > t` получил файл содержащий в себе более 17-ти тысяч таких строк `192.168.1.160`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в имени функции. connect() написанная мной конфликтовала с функцией из стандарта posix [connect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html)

```
int connect(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len)
```

Библиотека neon использует стандарт posix и функция connect используется для установки подключения (в прочем ничего другого от нее и не ожидалось). При это моя программа тоже имеет имя функции connect и при вызове функции `ne_sock_connect(...)` она вызывала функцию `connect(...)` не `<sys/socket.h>`, а мой `"webdav.h"` файла и программа уходила в рекурсию пока не заканчивались ресурсы системы.

Дав функции другое имя проблема сразу же исчезла.

P.S. После этого мне стало не хватать namespace из плюсов. XD